# Regex for set of 6 digits from 1-49

Tags: regex

I've a problem with define regular expression correctly. I want check sets of digits f.e.: 1,2,14,15,16,17 or 12,13,14,15,16,17 or 1,2,3,6,7,8. Every set contains 6 digits from 1 to 49. I check it by input's pattern field.

I wrote some regex but it works only for 2-digit sets.
`([1-9]|[1-4][0-9],){5}([1-9]|[1-4][0-9])`

Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: You need to group the number patterns separately from the comma and most probably anchor on both sides, `^(?:(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]),){5}(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9])$`, see https://regex101.com/r/a03xxT/1

Comment: Thanks man, it solves my problem!!!

Comment: What is the language, are you validating standalone strings?

Comment: Javascript, I want to do app whereby you can check your lottery score.

Comment: You may then split with `,`, check element count, and then case each element to a Number and check if it is between `1` and `49`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to group the number patterns inside the quantified group before comma and the anchors to make the regex engine match the full input string:

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]),){5}(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9])$
^   ^^^                ^                         ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a03xxT/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]),){5}` - five occurrences of:

  - `(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9])` - either a digit from `1` to `9` or a number from `10` to 49`
  - `,` - a comma
- `(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9])`
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['1,2,14,15,16,17','12,13,14,15,16,17', '1,2,3,6,7,8', '1,2,3,6,7,8,'];
var rng = '(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9])';
var rx = new RegExp("^(?:" + rng + ",){5}" + rng + "$");
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', rx.test(s));
}
```